# Should I authenticate DRF in that case in some way?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I made a react+django web app that is actually just a simple react form that sends data to django-rest-framework api view which saves form in database and sends an emails it to me.
React app does not utilize any user system, anyone can send their form.
Should I authenticate requests to DRF in some way? Also- when user types `www.example.com/api/modelapi` he can access the data- should i prevent this behaviour somehow?

Comment: Preventing  the access for everyone is a required. You can use permissions of DRF. [This link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) includes the answers of your problems. You already in use DRF just integrate permissions

Comment: @enesislam I undestand, but what is the correct approach since I don't use user system?

Comment: Do you want your API to be only used by the react app? Or do you want the endpoint to be completely public and without Auth?

Comment: To disable the browsable API just remove it from your settings. REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}

Comment: In that case? Which case do you mean?